# For F-distribution, find df1 and df2 given mode of PDF and height of PDF at mode?

Tags: distributions, mode, f-distribution

Are there closed form equations to find the degrees of freedom of an *F*-distribution (*df<sub>1</sub>* and *df<sub>2</sub>*), given the mode of the PDF and the height of the PDF at the mode? We can assume *df<sub>1</sub>* > 2. If the equations exist, what are they?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mode of the $F_{\nu_1,\nu_2}$ is at $\frac{\nu_1-2}{\nu_1}\!\cdot\!\frac{\nu_2}{\nu_2+2}$ (for $\nu_1>2$).

The density is

$$\frac{1}{\mathrm{B}\!\left(\frac{\nu_1}{2},\frac{\nu_2}{2}\right)} \left(\frac{\nu_1}{\nu_2}\right)^{\frac{\nu_1}{2}} x^{\frac{\nu_1}{2} - 1} \left(1+\frac{\nu_1}{\nu_2}\,x\right)^{-\frac{\nu_1+\nu_2}{2}}$$

(e.g. see Wikipedia on the [F-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-distribution))

If you know the mode (say $m$) and the density at the mode (say $\dot{f}$), then solving

\begin{eqnarray}
m&=&\frac{\nu_1-2}{\nu_1}\!\cdot\!\frac{\nu_2}{\nu_2+2}\\
\dot{f}&=&\frac{1}{\mathrm{B}\!\left(\frac{\nu_1}{2},\frac{\nu_2}{2}\right)} \left(\frac{\nu_1}{\nu_2}\right)^{\frac{\nu_1}{2}} m^{\frac{\nu_1}{2} - 1} \left(1+\frac{\nu_1}{\nu_2}\,m\right)^{-\frac{\nu_1+\nu_2}{2}}
\end{eqnarray}

simultaneously for ${\nu_1}, {\nu_2}$ will not generally be possible algebraically; you would have to proceed numerically as whuber explains in comments.

Note that it's easy to rearrange the first equation to get $\nu_1$ in terms of $m$ and $\nu_2$ (or to get $\nu_2$ in terms of $m$ and $\nu_1$), so that you can eliminate one of the d.f. variables and write the second equation in terms of $\dot{f}$, $m$ and one of the two d.f. variables.

Since you then have an equation in only one unknown, identifying the numerical solutions is not so onerous.

As an example, consider $m=0.4$ and $\dot{f}=0.65$. Eliminating $\nu_1$ as described, we can plot $\dot{f}$ as a function of $\nu_2$:

[image]

and readily identify an approximate solution to $\dot{f}=0.65$, yielding $\nu_2\approx 5.7$ (indeed, I calculated f(5.6) and f(5.7) in order to draw the plot, which were the two points with calculated function values closest to 0.65); a step or two of a suitable root-finding algorithm (*regula falsi* is fine in this case, though many stats packages will provide some more stable form of root-finding) quickly gives the result $\nu_2\approx 5.6683$.

We can then back out $\nu_1$, and get $\nu_1\approx 4.3586$.

A quick calculation of the original equations confirms these give the correct $m$ and $\dot{f}$ (to similar accuracy as we calculated $\nu_1$ and $\nu_2$ to).

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the clear description of how to go about the numerical solution in a way that makes it generalizable to other distributions.

Comment: For $0<\nu_1\le2$, is the mode of the distribution equal to $0$?

Comment: @Stubborn *Maybe.* It depends on just how you define the mode and possibly how you define the support of the F-distribution. If you define the density for $X$ on $(0,\infty)$, so that the variable is strictly positive (there's good reasons why you might choose to to exclude $0$, e.g. if you're starting from the ratio of scaled $\chi^2$s), your suggested mode is not actually in the support of the variable, which would be weird for something that's supposed to be the "most common" value. Nevertheless even in that case if you define it suitably in terms of limits then yes, you'd still say $0$.

Comment: I'd say most people would say it's zero without hesitation, but strictly it comes down to what our definitions were.